# How can I export .csv file using with Japanese character code in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create a csv file using laravel and php. The database used to create the csv contains Japanese characters which I want to appear exactly the same in the file.

Below is the code I've tried so far, but the japanese characters still appear as symbols.

```
$headers = array(
    "Content-Encoding" => "sjis-win",
    "Content-type" => "text/csv; charset=sjis-win",
    "Content-Disposition" => "attachment; filename=User-List.csv",
    "Pragma" => "no-cache",
    "Cache-Control" => "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0",
    "Expires" => "0"
);


$users= $this->users->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
$columns = array('氏名', '氏名（ローマ字）');

$callback = function() use ($users, $columns)
{
    $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    fputcsv($file, $columns);

    foreach($users as $user) {
        fputcsv($file, array($user->name, $user->name_alphabet));
    }
    fclose($file);
};
```

What am I missing? What needs to be changed to make the characters appear as Japanese automatically in the csv.

Comment: What encoding is your database in? Your `$headers` array suggests your saving the CSV as a 'sjis-win' encoded file. Unless the data is in the same encoding you will need to re-encode it using `mb_convert_encoding()`.

Comment: Thank you! My database is in UTF-8 format. Exactly where should I use the method you mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the data your retrieving from the database is encoded in **UTF-8**, you will need to re-encode that data to match the encoding of your CSV file (SJIS-win).

You can use php's [mb_convert_encoding()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) function to achieve this.

`mb_convert_encoding($dataVariable, "SJIS-win", "UTF-8");`

In your case you would use it as follows:

```
foreach($users as $user) {
    fputcsv($file, array(
        mb_convert_encoding($user->name, "SJIS-win", "UTF-8"), 
        mb_convert_encoding($user->name_alphabet, "SJIS-win", "UTF-8")
    ));
}
```

You may also need to re-encode the strings in your `$columns = array('氏名', '氏名（ローマ字）')` array too.

Answer (score 2):

```html
It working!

// You add $bom in when fputs file.
$headerColumns = [
   'name',
   'birthday',
   'address',
];

$fileCSV = fopen($fileName, 'w');
fputs($fileCSV, chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF));
fputcsv($fileCSV, $headerColumns);

foreach ($data as $myField ){
    fputcsv($fileCSV, $myField);
}

fclose($fileCSV);

// Good luck!
```